# Open jfx jar is not working in all operating sytems

Tags: java, openjfx

I followed the steps mentioned in Microsoft Windows 10
https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-build-openjfx-8-on-windows-from-source

It's working good with windows 10.

But If I move jfxrt.jar and other dependcies to Windows Server 2016, Its not working.

I have to follow the steps in Windows Server 2016 and have to create the jfxrt.jar to make it work.

Comment: javafx uses native libraries so you cannot transport those libraries to an incompatible platform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Could you please suggest an alterative solution.
If that is so, How it works in Oracle JDK. It has javafx libraries,

Comment: Alternative to what? Yes the oracle java8 jdk has the javafx libraries. I don't know enough about the build process, it might be possible to build a version that works for both windows. Do you use the same oracle jdk or is there a different one for each windows?

Comment: If used the link https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-build-openjfx-8-on-windows-from-source, for build process. Oracle JDK is not used here, Adopt open jdk is used. I used the adopt jdk in all operating systems

Comment: You built it on one windows, the way you built it means it is not compatible on the other windows. I don't know why you're telling me 'oracle jdk' is not used, you asked about it.